# Precision Arithmetic and Overflow for Factorial

Tags: precision, ieee-754, factorial, binomial-coefficients

Recall **IEEE Double Precision Arithmetic**. Now, for which `n > 1` can `binom(n,k)` be computed in IEEE Double Precision? Additionally on the same interval, when will intermediate factorial values overflow?

For my first question, I have found the interval **`n < 2^53`**. Not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: Just a comment (and this applies to your other [Factorial Overflow on an Interval for n>1](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229310/factorial-overflow-on-an-interval-for-n1) as well) but the title doesn't match the contents of the question. It's not clear whether you really mean `be computed`, or `be represented`. If the former, then using factorials would be a poor choice as far as both precision and performance go. Compare for example `binom(n, n-1) = n! / (n-1)! 1!` vs. `binom(n, n-1) = n`.

Comment: @dxiv I mean be represented. So how would I continue to show this? Is my first answer correct?

Comment: @manusolan, please put this information (that you are are asking about representation, not computation) in the question. And also please put correct tags next time.

Answer (score 1):

For a given `n` the largest `binom(n, k)` value is attained for `k = [n/2]` (integer part of `n/2`). For `binom(n, k)` to be representable in double precision precision format, it is therefore sufficient for `binom(n, [n/2])` to be representable.

The following lists the number of bits (binary digits) required for the exact representation of `binom(n, [n/2])` (retrieved from Wolfram Alpha using queries similar to [this one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+%2856+choose+28%29+to+base+2)).

```
 n       binom(n, [n/2])

56          53 bits
57          54 bits
```

The following lists the values in binary exponent form for `binom(n, [n/2])`.

```
 n       binom(n, [n/2])

1029     1.1... * 2^1023
1030     1.1... * 2^1024
```

The max `n` for which all `binom(n, k)` can be exactly represented in a double precision floating point (53 bits mantissa) is `56`.

The max `n` for which all `binom(n, k)` can be approximately represented in a double precision floating point (11 bit exponent) is `1029`.

The similar max limits for `n!` are n = `18` (exact representation) and n = `170` (floating point approximation).